# Extracting 200 lines from all the files in a folder

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I have a folder with a lot of CSV files. There are subfolders also. For each such file I need to extract the first 200 lines (to make a db sub sample) creating another file with these lines. So I would have several new files with 200 lines within each of them. I need to complete this task in Linux Ubuntu and using OS shell commands. Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Loops and the `top` command? What have you tried?

Comment: `find` and `head`

Comment: `split -l 200` is another option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line could respond to your need :

```
find . -type f -name "*.csv" -print|xargs -I@ sh -c 'head -n200 @ > @.headed'
```

This line is made with different part :

1. Find the files that must be "headed"
2. The output of the find command is just a list of files
3. xargs command that take the list of files and run on it the command pass with the sh -c option
4. The command that display the 200 first line of a file and put it in a filename with *"headed"* extension

With this line you have a solution that could be extensible for another usecase near the one you've written.